# Calcular campos en vista y pasar la consulta al template

Tags: python, django, django-views

Estoy usando Django 1.4 y tengo una consulta que trae de la db varios datos y entre ellos uno que puede tener 3 valores distintos(tipo). Dependiendo de ese datos hago un condicional y calculo unos valores (alojamiento y dieta) para enviar al template. Si lo hago solo con una línea en los datos me funciona bien, el problema es cuando tengo varias líneas en la que si me respeta los datos que vienen en el recordset (nombre, fecha y tipo) pero en los campos que calcula me pone en todas las líneas lo mismo.

Esto es lo que quiero.

```
nombre        tipo mes     alojamiento        dieta
nombre_1       1   enero   50                 45
nombre_2       2   febrero 60                 80
```

Donde:

- alojamiento = dias * importe_hotel --- los dias dependen del tipo.
- dietas = dias * importe_dieta  ---- los dos valores dependen del tipo.

Esto es lo que tengo.

```
nombre        tipo mes     importe_noche importe_dieta
nombre_1       1   enero   60                 80
nombre_2       2   febrero 60                 80
```

Lo he intentado con `aggregate`, pero me da error ya que los datos a calcular no están en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola Victor, tendrías que mostrar el queryset que estás tratando de hacer para poder ayudarte. También sería bueno ver tus modelos de otra forma no puedo saber como ayudarte con el query.

Answer (score 0):

Para varias lineas tienes que usar el "annotate", funciona de la misma manera que el "agregate" pero puede agrupar en varias filas, si pones tus modelos y la query te podré ayudar de manera más especifica